# How to create PDF of Report generate by Microsoft Dynamic CRM using WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, pdf, dynamics-crm

I am working on Microsoft Dynamic CRM. I can create PDF from Report of the Order. But I want to create PDF from WCF Service. I have order Id. I want to create PDF of that orderId using WCF Service.

I can add order, retrieve order details, product list or order etc.

Can anybody suggest me how to create PDF of Order in Microsoft Dynamic CRM?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On-Premise, where you can "talk" directly to the server, you could bypass CRM and invoke the Reporting Service URL which would let you download the PDF.

Online, sadly, it cannot be done (no SSRS to talk to).